# How many roots have a complex number with irrational exponent?

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-numbers

If a rational exponent on a complex number $z^q$ is the representation of a finite number of roots, then if the exponent is irrational this mean that there are infinite countable roots?

If this is the case... the cardinality of the number of roots is the same for any irrational exponent? Thanks in advance.

NOTE: there are different questions about irrational exponents but no one answer what Im searching so please dont mark this as repeated.

Comment: Nice! Had to read twice to understand what you're asking, but it's an interesting question. My intuition tells me that since an irrational number cannot be represented as a finite sum of rational numbers (but only as an infinite sum of rational numbers), the answer is yes. But I wouldn't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a simple example: $\sqrt[\Large\pi]1=\Big(e^{2k\pi~i}\Big)^\frac1{\Large\pi}=e^{2ki}=\cos\big(2k\big)+i\sin\big(2k\big)$, for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh, beautiful... because $2k$ never will be multiple of $\pi$ this means that there is an infinite number of different roots.

Comment: Does this include all possible angles? Ie. are these all the points of a circle centered at the origin, or is this only a subset of it?