# About the identity $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I have a question about the famous identity of Euler $e^{i\pi}=-1$. I opened the other day [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930666/how-many-roots-have-a-complex-number-with-irrational-exponent) about the number of roots of a complex number with irrational exponent.

Under this light and applying to Euler identity, it is the identity of Euler just a main value of infinity countable roots of $e^{i\pi}$? Its a convention or it is the unique value for the expression? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I will add some thoughts in relation to the comment of @Travis... may exist a "secret relation" under the surface when you do *exactly* this kind of exponentiation $e^{i\pi x}$ that "evade" the existence of infinite countable roots for the expression.

My thoughts are based in this analogy: $a^b=e^{b\log a}$. When you do this change of base we are putting, nearly sure, a irrational number on the exponent ($\log a$ for mainly all cases will be irrational) so if $a^b$ (with $a,b \in \Bbb N$) is equivalent to $e^{b\log  a}$ then we must assume one of three things:

1) This specific relation with irrational base $e$ and irrational exponent $b\log a$ dont create countable infinity roots, and analogously it doesnt happen with expressions derived from $e^{i\pi}$.

2) Or maybe that an irrational exponent doesnt means countable infinite roots, what is really counter-intuitive because you can decompose a irrational number in a countable infinite series of fractions (and a fraction as exponent is the expression for a finite number of roots).

3) Some arithmetic operations doesnt show the real nature of the operation, they have some degree of ambiguity for complex realm.

So these type of things that happen with exponentiation on the complex realm could show a "hide" relation between some specific irrational numbers.

Comment: For z complex number, the complex exponential function is defined to be $e^{z}=e^{Re(z)}(cos(Im(z))+isin(Im(z)))$. In this sense it's a convention but there are some reasons the exponential being defined this way.

Comment: You're on to something, see this: https://sites.google.com/site/taubeforeitwascool/

Comment: @mistermarko I know tau manifest ;). In a similar way, maybe a bit off-topic, seems very good for angles the concept of semicycle instead of radians all time because it put in direct relation naturals with division of a circle and is the natural unit for the alternative expression to Euler expression for complex numbers that is $f(x)=(-1)^x=e^{i\pi x}$. From this is easy to see the function as a helix on 3D counting the complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the unique value. For an exponential expression we write

$$a^b = \exp(b \log a),$$

and this indeed depends on a choice $\log$ of branch cut.

On the other hand, $z \mapsto \exp z$ requires no choice of branch cut, so there is no ambiguity in expressions like $\exp (i \pi)$.

Comment: Mmm... I know all of this but isnt clear that this is the "unique value". When we change the base doing $a^b=exp(b\log a)$ we are putting a nearly sure irrational exponent for no reason ($\log a$ generally is irrational). Maybe all is ok but notation must change in many ways for complex numbers, isnt enough good in many things.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, then it's still not clear to me what you mean. What equation do you mean when you ask whether its solution is unique?

Comment: To put my answer another way, if we are content to define (given a branch cut of $\log$) $a^b := \exp(b \log a)$, then we must have a well-defined notion of what the right-hand side (and $\exp$ in particular) means in the first place.

Comment: I will think about your contribution to this question but from my point of view now, to be fair, I dont see (by now) that what you says is a clear answer. I really appreciate any contribution but let me some time to think about it and conclude if what you says can answer my question or not.